# Nested Value/Key ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am having a lot of trouble getting a couple of nested ng-repeats to work in my code. I have a json object with couple of layers and i am trying to loop through the layers and display the data. Here is the structure of the json

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "Mat": {
        "total": 0,
        "pending_devices": 0,
        "individual_counts": {
            "Mat1": {
                "total": 0,
                "pending_devices": 0,
                "locations": []
            },
            "Mat2": {
                "total": 0,
                "pending_devices": 0,
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "location1": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "location2": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Cable": {
        "total": 0,
        "pending_devices": 0,
        "individual_counts": {
            "Flat Cable": {
                "total": 0,
                "pending_devices": 0,
                "locations": []
            },
            "L Cable": {
                "total": 0,
                "pending_devices": 0,
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "location1": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "location2": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here is the code i am using to loop through it:

```
<md-grid-tile ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.counts" class="{{vm.colors[$index]}}" md-rowspan="2">
  <md-grid-tile-body>
    <h2>Total:{{value.total}}</h2>
    <h2>Pending:{{value.pending_devices}}</h2>
    <p ng-repeat="(productType, productCounts) in value.individual_counts">
      <h3>{{productType}}:</h3>
      <h4>Total:{{productCounts.total}}</h4>
      <h4>Pending:{{productCounts.pending_devices}}</h4>
      <h4>Locations:</h4>
      <div ng-repeat="(location, locationCount) in productCounts.locations">
        <h5>{{location}}:{{locationCount}}</h5>
      </div>
    </p>
  </md-grid-tile-body>
  <md-grid-tile-footer>
    <h3>{{key}}</h3>
  </md-grid-tile-footer>
</md-grid-tile>
```

I am able to loop through the top level without any problem, but nothing is showing up for the productType/ProductTypeCount loop and below. I outputted value.individual_counts to verify it contained the correct data and it did. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using div instead of p. Paragraph elements can't contain block level elements.